# Typo3 6.2.4 / Extbase: Extending fe_users, error property not found

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I want to extend the fe_users table with some fields. 
My Model:

```
class Laeufer extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
...
```

Controller

```
/**
 * action new
 *
 * @param \Vendor\LhSponsorenlauf\Domain\Model\Laeufer $newLaeufer
 * @ignorevalidation $newLaeufer
 * @return void
 */
public function newAction(\Vendor\LhSponsorenlauf\Domain\Model\Laeufer $newLaeufer = NULL) {
    $this->view->assign('laeufer', $newLaeufer);
}
...
```

TS

```
plugin.tx_lhsponsorenlauf {
  persistence {
    classes {
      Vendor\LhSponsorenlauf\Domain\Model\Laeufer {
        mapping {
          tableName = fe_users
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I hit the create button of my new Action form I got the following error:

```
Exception while property mapping at property path "":Property "first_name" was not found in target object of type "Vendor\LhSponsorenlauf\Domain\Model\Laeufer"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it out by myself after writing and reading my own question. I disregarded the typo3 property name convention and took the columnname for my property name. But **first_name is firstName as property name**.